# Is it possible to predict the next number

Tags: logic, prediction, pattern-recognition

I have a query relating to pattern recognition in a series, can we get the 
    next number by just inputting a series based on any mathematical logic?

```
Input : 1, 10, 30, 68, ?
Output: 130. (or whatever logic fits )
```

Comment: That's going to be hard. There is a reason those things are used in IQ testing. You could theoretically train a non-linear model to approximate solutions to various kinds of mathematical functions. On the other hand you could hard-code some logics and detect them based on certain rules. I think both is rather complicated an  not really worthwhile.

Comment: This question is ill-defined. I could propose any number for the 5th one and find a justification for it. Suppose I pick 146. I can argue this is correct because the rest of the pattern is "alternate between multiply by two and adding eight, and multiplying by two and adding ten". I could give 884 and claim the rule has to do with iterating through factors according to a rule. These are just two examples I was able to come up with in a couple of minutes. There are infinitely many correct answers. Do you want "the best" one? What criteria are you using?

Comment: i  want an output, based upon a mathematical logic which follows the series, well it wasn't about adding eight or anything, i just want to know that, is it possible to design an algorithm which is generalized to find logic or a pattern in occurrence of numbers.